Sign Invalid when using Tuya API
I'm trying to connect to Tuya API to get an access token. However, when I test it, it gives me a "sign invalid" error, specifically the next one:
{"code":1004,"msg":"sign invalid","success":false,"t":1729521181672,"tid":"602726268fb911ef844fc2ceb152d8fe"}
As far as I go, I've tried with this code:
const CryptoJS = require('crypto-js');

function getTime() {
    return new Date().getTime();
}

(function () {
    var timestamp = getTime();
    pm.environment.set("timestamp", timestamp);

    const clientId = "HERE I'VE PUT MY CLIENT ID";
    const secret = "HERE I'VE PUT MY CLIENT SECRET";

    if (!clientId || !secret) {
        console.error("clientId or secret is undefined!");
        return;
    }

    var nonce = generateNonce();
    pm.request.headers.add({ key: "nonce", value: nonce }); // Ensure nonce is a string

    const httpMethod = pm.request.method.toUpperCase();
    const query = pm.request.url.query || "";
    const headersStr = "Content-Type: application/json";

    // Generate string to sign
    var signStr = stringToSign(httpMethod, headersStr, query);
    console.log("String to sign:", signStr); // Log for debugging
    
    // Set the request URL
    pm.request.url = "https://openapi.tuyaeu.com/v1.0/token?grant_type=1";

    if (!clientId || !timestamp || !signStr) {
        console.error("clientId, timestamp or signStr is undefined or empty!");
        return;
    }

    var sign = calcSign(clientId, timestamp, nonce, signStr, secret);
    pm.environment.set('easy_sign', sign);

    console.log("Client ID:", clientId);
    console.log("Timestamp:", timestamp);
    console.log("Nonce:", nonce);
    console.log("Calculated Sign:", sign);
})();

function calcSign(clientId, timestamp, nonce, signStr, secret) {
    var str = clientId + timestamp + nonce + signStr;
    var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(str, secret);
    return hash.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64).toUpperCase();
}

function stringToSign(method, headersStr, query) {
    var sha256 = CryptoJS.SHA256(headersStr).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex);
    var url = query ? "?" + query : "";
    return method + "\n" + sha256 + "\n" + url;
}

function generateNonce() {
    return Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15);
}
});

How can I correct it?
